# subsetting data with multiple conditions using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with columns DX1 to DX10  with character variables coded with iCD9codes for example
I would like to filter my data set with the codes 4289, 4281, 4282 that lies anywhere from DX1 to DX10

Any easier way to do that using dplyr?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcoQD.jpg)

Comment: Update your question with real data (not pictures). Also, what's easy? For some users base R is easier than dplyr

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data aren't particularly helpful.

Comment: Are you saying that you want all rows where at least one of those three numbers appear?

Comment: @p0bs question is very unclear (maybe he wants rows, maybe columns, maybe all, maybe one value)

Comment: @PoGibas - Agreed - Just trying to elicit a little more detail in steps

Comment: Reshape to long form, then `longDF %>% group_by(whatever) %>% filter(any(code %in% my_fav_codes))` or the same with `all` instead of `any` ... hard to be more specific without a complete example per MrFlick's link.

Comment: I am trying with the following code :x<- Y %>% filter(DX1%in% c("4289", "4281", "4282")). How can I include multiple columns in this code?

Comment: It's easier if your data is transformed to long form, I think. Anyway, if you make it reproducible (both input and output), someone can probably answer a lot more quickly and comprehensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to retain all the columns from your original dataset, there are 2 ways to go around this:

**1.** Use `filter_all` to filter all columns. This is assuming that your dataset contains only from DX1 - DX10

Input:

```
set.seed(10)
df <- tibble(DX1 = sample(4280:4380, 10),
             DX2 = c(4281, sample(4200:4500, 9)),
             DX3 = sample(4270:4310, 10),
             DX4 = sample(4280:4295, 10))

df
# A tibble: 10 x 4
     DX1   DX2   DX3   DX4
   <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
 1  4331 4281.  4304  4285
 2  4310 4396.  4310  4288
 3  4322 4370.  4293  4281
 4  4347 4233.  4299  4282
 5  4288 4377.  4283  4290
 6  4301 4306.  4284  4284
 7  4306 4326.  4294  4287
 8  4305 4215.  4298  4289
 9  4337 4277.  4277  4294
10  4319 4316.  4309  4291
```

Method:

```
df %>% filter_all(any_vars(. == 4282 | . == 4281 | . == 4289))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
    DX1   DX2   DX3   DX4
  <int> <dbl> <int> <int>
1  4331 4281.  4304  4285
2  4322 4370.  4293  4281
3  4347 4233.  4299  4282
4  4305 4215.  4298  4289
```

**2.** Use `filter_at` to filter certain columns. This is assuming that your dataset also contains other columns besides DX1 - DX10.

Input:

```
set.seed(124)
df2 <- tibble(DX1 = sample(4280:4380, 10),
              DX2 = c(4281, sample(4200:4500, 9)),
              DX3 = sample(4250:4350, 10),
              DX4 = sample(4280:4300, 10),
              AA1 = sample(4280:4295, 10),
              AA2 = c(sample(4500:5500, 9), 4289))

df2
# A tibble: 10 x 6
     DX1   DX2   DX3   DX4   AA1   AA2
   <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1  4288 4281.  4253  4288  4285 4649.
 2  4320 4432.  4312  4296  4282 4920.
 3  4331 4457.  4309  4285  4291 5335.
 4  4318 4426.  4257  4287  4288 5020.
 5  4301 4453.  4290  4294  4294 4717.
 6  4308 4321.  4282  4281  4284 4746.
 7  4335 4216.  4269  4299  4283 4864.
 8  4326 4370.  4328  4282  4292 4731.
 9  4365 4419.  4274  4292  4281 5239.
10  4305 4459.  4326  4295  4289 4289.
```

Method:

```
df2 %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("DX")), any_vars(. == 4282 | . == 4281 | . == 4289))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
     DX1   DX2   DX3   DX4   AA1   AA2
   <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1  4288 4281.  4253  4288  4285 4649.
 2  4308 4321.  4282  4281  4284 4746.
 3  4326 4370.  4328  4282  4292 4731.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- Y %>%
    gather(key = "DX", value = "code", starts_with("DX")) %>%
    filter(DX %in% c("4289", "4281", "4282"))
```

As Frank noted in comments, `dplyr` works best when data is tidy, meaning variables are in columns and observations are in rows. Use `tidyr::gather` to combine the data into two columns, one `key` column named `DX` that tells you what column that value came from, and a `value` column, here called `code`, that is the number in the cell.
Then it is easy to use `filter` because there is only one column you need, the new `DX` column.

See this chapter on [tidy data](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
z<-Y %>% 
filter(DX1%in% c("4289", "4281","4282") | DX2%in% c("4289", "4281", "4283") | DX3 %in% c("4289", "4281", "4283") | DX4 %in% c("4289", "4281", "4283")| DX5%in% c("4289", "4281", "4283")| DX6 %in% c("4289", "4281", "4283") | DX7%in% c("4289", "4281", "4283") | DX8%in% c("4289", "4281", "4283")| DX9%in% c("4289", "4281", "4283")| DX10%in% c("4289", "4281", "4283"))
```